# JSON Data Object Handling in React

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment

Cant figure it out how to extract data from parsed and stored json object from state ... i have tried many ways but getting errors (data from openweathermap)

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      data: null
    };
  }
  getWeather(url) {
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data =>
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
              data: data
            })
        )
        .catch(error => console.log("Error Loading data " + error));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      const url = `${API}lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&${APPID}`;
      this.getWeather(url);
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div>
          {console.log(this.state.data)}
          {/*renders json*/}
          <h1>{this.state.data.name}</h1>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add your example json.

Comment: @Kaushik `{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":282.54,"pressure":993,"humidity":66,"temp_min":281.48,"temp_max":283.71},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":240},"rain":{},"clouds":{"all":20},"dt":1573139094,"sys":{"type":1,"id":1412,"country":"GB","sunrise":1573110235,"sunset":1573143868},"timezone":0,"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you might be getting `cannot read property 'name' of null`. Not sure about the exact error but something like that.

Try to use

```
<h1>{ this.state.data && this.state.data.name }</h1>
```

Till the time API is not giving the response, your data in the state is `null` so you cannot access `data.name`.

Comment: this trick worked, thanks . But i am not getting why is this in this way !

Comment: As I told, it might be possible that when component rendered, `this.state.data` would be `null` as you have set in the constructor. The data variable is filled once you get back the response from the API which is an async call so it will take some time to get the result. Till that time, at least once render will be called and thus because of having `this.state.data` as null, you won't be having `this.state.data.name` which will result in an error.